# Шифруются ли данные при копирование файлов функцией SHFileOperation

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, шифрование

Я использую SHFileOperation для копирования файлов с одних удаленных компов на другие, но передача данных должна быть защищена. На msdn'е я ничего не нашёл. Где можно узнать, шифруются данные, или нет?

Comment: Посмотрите любым сниффером (netmon, wireshark, например), по какому протоколу ходят данные от вашей программы. SSL - значит шифруются. Если какой-то другой протокол - читайте документацию по этому протоколу (SSL иногда может быть инкапсулирован)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная функция использует обращение к файлам как к объектам операционной системы. Так что, думаю, тут используются стандартные вызовы WinAPI. Соответственно, данные копируемых файлов будут использоваться согласно настройкам установленных сетевых протоколов. C большей долей вероятности в сети с клиентами и серверами на базе Windows - это будет протокол SMB. Шифрование же этого протокола задается административной политикой. А в старых версиях протокола, к примеру SMB 1.0 - на шифрование надеяться вообще не стоит. Так что вопрос следует перед собой поставить так: а обеспечивает ли используемая среда (сеть) требуемый уровень шифрования?